# MySQL How to Limit first "order by" results

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have the following sql query:

```
"SELECT id, case, value 
FROM tbl1 
WHERE (case > '100' OR case is null) 
ORDER BY case DESC, value DESC"
```

The result is something like this:

---

```
| id   | case     | value  |
 -------------------------- 
| 17   | case1    | value1 |
| 16   | case2    | value2 |
| 14   | case3    | value3 |
| 18   | empty    | value4 |
| 15   | empty    | value5 |
```

It gives me for example 100 results where "case" is set. an 500 where "case" is empty.

Now i only need the 20 first results where "case" is SET and 100 results where "case" is EMPTY.

If i do the following:

```
"SELECT id, case, value 
FROM tbl1 ... 
ORDER BY case DESC,value DESC 
LIMIT 0,120"
```

It gives me all the values where "case" is set... But I only want 20.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're best off unioning 2 queries

```
SELECT id, case, value 
FROM tbl1 
WHERE CASE IS NOT NULL
LIMIT 20
UNION
SELECT id, case, value 
FROM tbl1 
WHERE CASE IS NULL
ORDER BY case DESC
LIMIT 100
```

Comment: Thanks for your help,I am getting an error saying "Incorrect usage of UNION and ORDER BY"  but i suppose that's because I am using a LEFT JOIN. I will figure that out.

Comment: @user2129830 I fixed my answer. The ORDER BY can only be at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [`union`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/union.html)

```
SELECT id, case, value 
FROM tbl1 
WHERE case > '100'
ORDER BY case DESC, value DESC
limit 20
union
SELECT id, case, value 
FROM tbl1 
WHERE case is null
ORDER BY case DESC, value DESC
limit 100
```

Comment: Thank you for the help.
I accepted the first answer, because both were nearly the same. But many thanks also to you.